# Input hexadecimal value in multiple unsigned char variable

Tags: c, char, hex, scanf, unsigned

I've just started working with hex values (in c language) and below is the code:

```
int main(){

    unsigned char x, y, z;
    scanf("%x", &x);
    scanf("%x", &y);
    scanf("%x", &z);
    printf("val are: %x, %x, %x\n",x,y,z);
    return 0
}
```

In the above code, why is the value of `x` and `y` is getting lost/overwritten and how can I solve it?

Comment: would you please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HARSHGUPTA you used `%x` instead of `%2hhx`. That's what you did wrong.

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, for `%x` conversion specifier, (__emphasis mine_)

> `x`
>
> Matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer, whose format is the same
>   as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value
>   16 for the base argument. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   unsigned integer.**

You are supplying the argument as a pointer to a `unsigned char`.

Also, from same chapter, P10

> [...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a `*`, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.

So, your code invokes undefined behaviour.

You need to use the format specifier as `%hhx`, if the argument is a pointer to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

qualifier "%x" works with integer type.
You can enable compiler warnings and compiler will warn you about misuse of types.
you variables are on stack and occupy close addresses.
scanf interprets passed adresses as addresses to variable which occupies more that single byte.
that is the reason why scanf overwrites your variables.
you can replace type of your variables to int to avoid your issue

```
int main(){

    unsigned int x, y, z;
    scanf("%x", &x);
    scanf("%x", &y);
    scanf("%x", &z);
    printf("val are: %x, %x, %x\n",x,y,z);
    return 0
}
```